# Do all the cars in NFS Most Wanted become the same after upgrading them to their max?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

Do all the cars have the same abilities if they are upgraded to the max of their attributes in NFS Most wanted?

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't even after max upgradation and junkman parts, the Carrera GT could reach 380 KmPH. But the lowest cars have difficulty reaching 330 KmPH and the slightest steering causes a greater reduction in speed, at higher speeds.

**PS**: I used cheats to upgrade the cars (but didn't play online).